# mouseover to show full data of cell

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table of rows that have various bits of data in it.  One of the fields "name" could contain a string with unknown length.  To make the table look good, if its length is greater then 35, the value of $name is a substring of the whole value.

```
    if (strlen($value['name']) > 35)
    {
            $name = substr($value['name'],0,35) . "......";
    }
    else
    {
            $name = $value['name'];
    }
    echo "<tr id='" . $value['number'] . "'>";
            echo "<td width='10%'>" . $value['number'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width='30%'>" . $name . "</td>";
            echo "<td width='10%'>" . $value['date_entered'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width='10%'>" . $value['date_modified'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width='1%'>" . $value['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
```

so "This is a name with a very long string of data in it"
 becomes
 "This is a name with a very long....."

what I am trying to do is create a mouseover affect that if you mouseover this cell, it will   show the full value in a small popup window.

```
 <script>

 $(function(){

 $('tr').hover(function () {

 <<show some data here>>
});
});
</script>
```

a few questions.

1. How do i define the selector. this table could have numerous rows, so how can i tell the selector to get the value of the cell on the row im currently moused over?
2. how do i pass the value of the cell to jquery for display?

I have tried this from another SO post.

```
  $('#tickets tr').each(function() {
var ticketName = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();    
    alert(ticketName);

 });
```

this shows every single ticket's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.How do i define the selector. this table could have numerous rows, so how can i tell the selector to get the value of the cell on the row
>   im currently moused over?

The value of `this` in event handlers is the targeted element. So just use

```
$('tr').hover(function () {

 var ticketName = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
});
```

> 2.how do i pass the value of the cell to jquery for display?

Generate javascript code from your PHP side that will assign your full name value to the element,
like `"$(tr#".$value['number'].")[0].fullName =".$value['name']`. You can then access `this.fullName` in your handler.

(I feel this is the cleanest way for 2., other ways are adding HTML elements with the `display: none` styling to store the info or adding custom attributes to your tr element.)

Comment: perfect, I got the hover working perfect.  getting the data may be a bit more work, I threw in some test data and i can see the concept.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
if (strlen($value['name']) > 35)
{
        $name = substr($value['name'],0,35) . "......";
        $hove = true;
}
else
{
        $name = $value['name'];
        $hover = false;
}
echo "<tr id='" . $value['number'] . "'>";
        echo "<td width='10%'>" . $value['number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='30%' ";
        echo 'data-shorttext="'.$name.'" ';
        echo 'data-fulltext="'.$value['name'].'">';
        echo $name . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'>" . $value['date_entered'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'>" . $value['date_modified'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='1%'>" . $value['status'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#tickets tr').hover(function() {
     var $elmt = $(this);
     $elmt.html(elmt.data('fulltext')); 
},
function() {
     var $elmt = $(this);
     $elmt.html(elmt.data('shorttext')); 
});
```

The php code assigns `date-fulltext` and `date-shorttext` attributes to the elements, which are then used by the jQuery hover event handlers to change the element's content. Please note that this is more a proof of concept than working and tested code, it's just to get the idea.
See [jQuery hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerIneventObject-handlerOuteventObject) and [jQuery data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) functions for reference.